# When AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin Widget is back on screen, how to refresh it?

Tags: flutter, dart, refresh

I have a tab page with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, which works well.

What I want is, when switch back to this page, I can choose refresh this page or not.

As far as I know, `wantKeepAlive` seems work on when widget is displayed.

I also checked life cycle of State. Method like `initState`, `activate`. None of them worked.

So my question is, Will there be any thing triggered when `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` Widget is back on screen?

Or if `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` can't do that, is there any other way to keep page state, and

Comment: When you say "I can choose refresh this page or not", what do you mean? What would be a trigger to refresh?

Comment: It's a state from http request, when this page is off screen. I only want to check the state and refresh the page when the page is back on screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Navigator.pop(context, false);**

you can use this on screen

when you send to new screen

```
    final return = Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<bool>());
if(return){
//
}else{
//
}
```

Comment: It's a page view with tabbar(like the TabBarController in iOS) , not the push and pop one.

Comment: Can you share what you have done ?

Answer (score 0):

Move the state up from the page (tab) to parent and initiate refresh in [onTap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/onTap.html) of `TabBar`.

```dart
TabBar(
  onTap: (index) {
    // TODO
  },
  controller: _controller,
  tabs: const <Widget>[
    ...
  ],
),
```

For a more elegant solution take a look at [Simple app state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Comment: I still want to know what happens to the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, but this is a good idea.